# Subgit and svn commit message hook

Tags: git, svn, version-control, subgit

We are using subgit to sync git and svn and there is a svn hook for checking commits messages format.

We found that we are limited on which git action we can perform without violating the svn hook. For example:

git commit -m 'XYZ: abc'
  git push.
  works ok.

git tag -a 1.0.0 -m 'XYZ: abc'
  git push 1.0.0
  the svn hook will fail because subgit is not attaching the message when syncing to svn.

And so on.

Is there a solution to this beside using git --alow-empty to fake a message or performing the action in svn and wait to sync?

Regards.

Comment: For SubGit 2.0.x and at least for SubGit 3.0.0, using --allow-empty trick is the only workaround, unfortunately.

Comment: In the latest SubGit version there's also svn.svnCommitMessage option, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227319/subgit-use-svn-svncommitmessage-option for details. It's still not exactly what you're asking for but it's an alternative: pre-defined message pattern for changes in Git that create no additional commits (e.g. pure tags or branches creation without changes).