# SubGit: use svn.svnCommitMessage option

Tags: git, svn, subgit

Just seen this feature in the SubGit 3.2.4 release notes:

> Support for svn.gitCommitMessage and svn.svnCommitMessage options that allow specifying message patterns used by SubGit while generating commit messages.

But i cannot find any example on the syntax.
I want to do a one time import, so i guess i run

```
subgit configure SVN_REPO repo.git
```

then edit `repo.git/subgit/config` and add `gitCommitMessage` to the `svn` section. But what are the variables/placeholders i can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the placeholders that can be used:

- %author = Git author (available in both directions)
- %committer = Git committer (available in both directions)
- %date =  date of revision or commit (available in both direction)
- %message = original message (available in both direction)
- %note = Git commit note stored at refs/notes/commits (available in Git => SVN direction)
- %note(refs/notes/namespace) = Git commit note stored at refs/notes/namespace (available in Git => SVN direction)
- %commit = Git commit hash (available in Git => SVN direction)
- %svnUser = Subversion username (available in both directions)
- %revision = Subversion revision, GRN in your notation (available in SVN => Git direction)
- %branch = Subversion branch (available in both directions)
- \n = newline feed (available in both directions)

Examples:

```
[svn]
svnCommitMessage = "%message\n\nr%revision %branch"
```

or

```
[svn]
svnCommitMessage = "%message\n%note(refs/notes/test)\n\nr%revision %branch"
```

Comment: Thanks! Where exactly you got these infos from? Looks like my google-fu wasnt strong enough here, but their documentation seem not updated yet.

Answer (score 1):

sorry to answer that late.
Now the information is available in the documentation, namely:

the svnCommitMessage option description:

https://subgit.com/config-options.html#svn.svnCommitMessage

available placeholders:

```
%author = Git author    
%committer = Git committer    
%date = Git commit date    
%message = original message    
%note = Git commit note stored under refs/notes/commits    
%note(refs/notes/namespace) = Git commit note stored under 
refs/notes/namespace
%commit = Git commit hash
%svnUser = Subversion username
%branch = Subversion branch
\n = newline feed
```

the gitCommitMessage option description:

https://subgit.com/config-options.html#svn.gitCommitMessage

supported placeholders:

```
%author = Git author    
%committer = Git committer    
%date = date of revision    
%message = original message    
%svnUser = Subversion username    
%revision = Subversion revision, GRN in your notation    
%branch = Subversion branch    
\n = newline feed
```